# IIS website with double login option

Tags: asp.net, iis, active-directory, sitecore

I need to allow users to login website either with their Active Directory accounts if they are in local network (Sitecore's single sign-on functionality) or with their credentials (email and social security number) if they access site being outside local network.

First option could be achieved by enabling Windows Authentication mode in IIS and second - by using Anonymous mode. But it is impossible to enable these two modes at the same time for one site. So the question is how to configure website in IIS to allow both groups of users login it with appropriate option and do not create different site for each option?

Any good ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I entirely understand completely, but it sounds like Sitecore's switching security provider might lead you in the right direction. http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/sitecore6modules/ad/low-level_sitecore_cms_security_and_custom_providers.pdf

Comment: Martin, thanks for your suggestion, but it is not exactly what I meant. Please read my comment to jRobbins answer, maybe there I explained my problem more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the Sitecore interface, you can disable Windows Authentication and your AD users can still log in by specifying the domain as part of their username, e.g. `<AD-Domain>\AD-username` and then supplying their AD password. If you have followed the [Sitecore Active Directory Module Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/AD/AD12/Documentation.aspx) then domain in this instance should be `ad` but you can change this to whatever you like, just make sure the rest of the config and references to "ad" have been changed to match.

In order to still allow Single Sign On without the user having to type in their domain/username/password you need to remove Anonymous and enable Windows Authentication for the login file only located at `/sitecore/admin/ldaplogin.aspx`. See section 4.3.1 of the documentation.

[image: Ldap Page Authentication]

In order to use this Single Sign On page and login, your AD users need to browser to `http://<your-site>/sitecore/admin/ldaplogin.aspx`. I provided a link on Sitecore login page by creating an HTML page with a link to this page:

```
<html>
<body>
    <a href="/sitecore/admin/ldaplogin.aspx">Login with your Windows account</a>
</body>
<html>
```

And then updating the `Login.SitecoreUrl` setting to the html page:

```
<!--  LOGIN SITECORE URL
      Specifies the Url of the Sitecore pane on the login startpage.
-->
<setting name="Login.SitecoreUrl" value="/sitecore/admin/ldaplogin.html" />
```

Your users will then be provided with a link in the pane on the right side of the login page for Sitecore 7.5 and earlier.

[image: Sitecore login screen]

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore does have its own Active Directory module that its worth investigating. The links to documents are broken currently so can't find the exact answer to help you.

Here is the link to the main page and download - [sdn.sitecore.net/Products/AD.aspx](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/AD.aspx)

It's their own Module so if you do have any questions or issues you can raise a support ticket with them.

Comment: jRobbins, thanks for your reply. Actually, Sitecore's LDAP module is configured and used by site and users who have accounts in AD can login the site automatically when Windows Authentication is enabled in IIS. But in this case users who don't have accounts in AD, can't access the site being asked by IIS to authorize first time. These users are able to access site only when Anonymous mode is enabled. The problem is that enabling both modes is not allowed and I don't know any way how to configure site that users from AD can login and users from not AD can access.

Comment: I've only ever used mixed-AD in the Sitecore interface, but the AD user will need to specify the domain also, e.g. using `<AD-Domain>\AD-Username` format. You can then remove the Windows Authentication, or provide a different link for those users to allow auto-login.

Comment: Thanks,  jammykam, I'll try it.  
And what do you mean under different link? Could you please give some example?